# What are some of the software cost estimation methods and models?

Tags: software-estimation

I'm doing some research on software cost estimation models and methods with a few colleagues of mine, and I was just wondering if you guys knew any specifically other than the ones listed below. Thanks!

Models:

- The Planning Game
- COCOMO / COCOMO II
- SLIM
- SEER-SEM
- Weighted Micro Function Points
- Program Evaluation and Review Technique
- PRICE Systems
- Wideband Delphi
- Function Point Analysis
- Evidence-based Scheduling

Methods:

- Expert Judgment Method
- Analogy Method
- Parametric / Algorithmic Method
- Bottom-Up/Work Breakdown Structure Method
- Top-Down Method
- Analysis Effort Method
- Proxy-Based Estimation Method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's also the REVIC model mainly used for government projects (as used by http://sepo.spawar.navy.mil/Estimation.html), I've found the Weighted Micro Function Points cost model (as used by http://www.projectcodemeter.com) to be the most useful since it's more suitable for measuring small increments in code development.